# match regular expression

Tags: ruby

I have to requirement to check the value `91981552e1775310VgnVCM100000a2b6140a____;standard;212.58.244.70;Oct-22-2012;24353teehdtehg;` where the date and `24353teehdtehg` is dynamic.

How can I may it more generic so that I can check `expected_value =~/actual_value/` excluding the dynamic values in Ruby.

Comment: Why [is a regex the right solution?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html). Sure, they're code-studly but don't you have you something better to do with your time than try to find one that works and will continue to work if your target changes? I'd use `split(';')` on the string and move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regular expression if at all possible. You seem to have an input string that can easily be altered and used to compare against an expected value without using a regular expression.

```
str = "91981552e1775310VgnVCM100000a2b6140a____;standard;212.58.244.70;Oct-22-2012;24353teehdtehg;"

actual_value = str.split(';')[0..-3].join(';')
# "91981552e1775310VgnVCM100000a2b6140a____;standard;212.58.244.70"
```

Then just compare the two

```
expected_value == actual_value
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use something like :

```
/91981552e1775310VgnVCM100000a2b6140a____;standard;212\.58\.244\.70;(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2}-\d{4};\d{5}[a-z]{9};/
```

depending on what the string could actually be.